# Issues in video connection in chrome browser

Tags: angular, agora-web-sdk-ng

The issue arises when I try to connect video call in Angular web application in Chrome browser. Though it's working fine with Safari and Firefox browsers.

The video call connects in Chrome when I run the code on localhost, but it throws a "permission denied" error when I try to run it on the server. This only happens with Chrome browser.

This is the error that I get when I try to run the video call on the server in Chrome

[image]